How to move script files from index.html to angular.json
I've been tasked with moving some script files in our index.html out; my options are, apparently, either package.json via npm or into the angular.json; I've opted for the later as we have very specific versions of some files.
As it stands, all the files are located in a folder called lib:

src/main/app/js/lib/*.js

The files are things like jquery, underscore, moment etc (this is an application that was once angularjs, hence the addition of jquery yester-year) and are very specific versions that the team want to keep.
I added the jquery entries only to the scripts portion of the angular.json as a proof of concept but this breaks the application (the ui is messed up but there is no console error).

So what's the problem here?

in angular.json can you put in script array, path: projects/<project-name>/architect/build/options/scripts

Thats what I'm doing - that screenshot is of the scripts array in the angular.json file.

Do something to narrow down or reproduce the problem.

@PetrAveryanov What do you suggest? I've said removing the files from index.html and moving them to the angular.json file breaks the ui with no console errors, hence why I'm stuck.

@Katana24 append src/ before every path and try

@Katana24 I would start with small angular project with one standard jquery in scripts.  And then u move step-by-step adding more stuff.

You do indeed need to move the scripts to the angular.json but this is only part of the answer.
What I found that worked for me, using Angular 18, was that after the "scripts": "app/js/lib/jquery.min.js" has been updated in the angular.json (you don't need to move them to the assets folder) you only need to update the files that make use of that script with:
declare var $: any;
Other answers have mentioned that you only need to update the typings.d.ts (add it to the root of the src folder if it doesn't exist) but that didn't work for me; the application just didn't compile.

First place the scripts inside the folder src/assets.
Then make sure you configured assets folder in the assets array of angular.json.
...
 "assets": ["src/assets"],
...
"scripts": ["src/assets/jquery.min.js"],
...


Below is a working example, where I place JQuery in the assets folder and then point to in inside the scripts array of angular.json.
Stackblitz Demo
